# Angular resource action resulting in nested req in node/express

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, angular-resource

I'm building an AngularJS and NodeJS/Express application.

All AngularJS resources are operating as expected except for the custom action I added which results in req.params and req.body in Express being undefined. Instead I've found that these objects are nested under req, as in req.req.params and req.req.body which are the values I would expect at req.params and req.body. I believe the AngularJS custom action is causing req to be nested. Why is this happening, and what can I do to "unnest" req?

**AngularJS resource declaration** (addUser is the problem child):

```
.factory('Account', function($resource){
  return $resource('/api/account/:id', null, {
    'update': { method: 'PUT' },
    'addUser': { 
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/api/account/:id/addUser' 
    } 
  });
})
```

**How addUser is being called:**

```
Account.addUser({ id: accountId }, postData, function(){
  console.log('success');
};
```

**The route in node/express:**

```
app.post('/api/account/:id/addUser', function(req, req) {
  console.log(req.params, req.body);           // results in...  undefined, undefined
  console.log(req.req.params, req.req.body);   // results in values as expected of req.params and req.body
});
```

I've read and re-read custom actions at the below URL and don't see what I'm doing wrong. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: what is `postData` and what is actually getting sent in the POST? You can see that in the network tab of your browser.

Comment: DOH...the route had function(req, req) instead of function(req, res). That caused really bad things to happen. Correcting that solved all my issues.

Comment: Ah so it did. Too bad V8 didn't alert you to that :-/

Comment: Well it's not really an error since it's just the naming of the arguments inside a private function. I had them switched (res, req) and it caused the same issue.

Comment: But if the two parameters are named exactly the same, how can any code differentiate which you are really referring to? I think naming them the same is a completely different situation from naming then different but inconsistent with expectations.

Answer (score 2):

Stupid programming error...

The route had `function(req, req)` instead of `function(req, res)`. That caused really bad things to happen. Correcting that solved all my issues.

Comment: Super weird but I had EXACTLY the same issue, even down to the angular $resource call. Same solution. :p Ha!